# Entity Framework Count Efficiency

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I query the school entity from the database. And then, I try to get the number of students in that school by doing this:

```
var school = context.schools.Where(s=>s.ID == 1).Single();
int cnt = school.students.Count();
```

But I see that the query sent to database gets all the student records in that school, and the counting is done on the application server.

Whereas the following just queries the COUNT() from the database, as it should be:

```
int cnt = context.students.Where(s=>s.schoolID == 1).Count();
```

Why is there such a difference between these two approaches? Shouldn't the first query also use COUNT() to be efficient?

Note: Not querying the school entity is not an option because I am using some of its fields.

Comment: Does the extension method .Single take in a IEnumerable <T> or IQueryable <T>?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It returns IQueryable if that's what you are asking.

Comment: `Note: Not querying the school entity is not an option because I am using some of its fields.` - query school and make count in 2 different queries

Comment: you not making sense, if it was the count then change `var` as in `var school` to int, as you can see its not the count but the entire row/entity.

Comment: sometime the easiest is, include the SQL you would of written and we convert it to linq. also some are mixing what lazy loading actually is, i suggest you read up on it, as i am getting mixed feelings about other understanding in here.

Answer (score 2):

`school.students.Count()` working via **LazyLoading**, so at first, you fetch students: `school.students` and then `.Count()` them on client side, as you already wrote. But you can modify your code the way, which will perform one trip to database:

```
var answer = (from sch in context.schools
              where sch.ID == 1
              join st in context.students on sch.ID equals st.schoolID into subs
              from sub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
              group sub by new { sch.ID, sch.Name, sch.Location } into gr
              select new 
              {
                  gr.Key.Name,
                  gr.Key.Location,
                  Count = gr.Count(x => x != null)
              }).First();
```

`sch.Name`, `sch.Location` - school's fields, which you need for further use

Answer (score 2):

Queries are run at the last possible moment to make them as efficient as possible - called Lazy Loading - and in your first example your `Single()` call forces the data provider to be less lazy than you might like.

When you call `Single()`, you're asking for an entire `Student` record - the first in the list of all student records, so the query has to run (`GET SchoolId, SchoolName, .... FROM SCHOOLS WHERE SchoolId = 1`) to get you that data. Then afterwards you call `Count()`, replaying the query except only selecting `COUNT`.

Instead in your second example, you call `Count()` only after a `Where()` call. `Where()` doesn't force the query to play because you haven't accessed any data yet, so the data provider can smartly only play a `GET COUNT` - type query on the database after it evaluates `Count()`.

How to tell if a LINQ method will 'play' your query? The way I remember is that if it returns `IQueryable<T>` it will *not* play your query, anything else, it will.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the lazy loading, but the effect is two-fold:

1. `context.schools.Where(s=>s.ID == 1).Single()` will return a school entity without any students loaded (lazy loading part 1). But,
2. `school.students.Count()` has to hit the database for all students because of the `.students` part - since they were not loaded in on the first line, they will be all be loaded in (because you implicitly asked for that - lazy loading part 2) *then* the `Count()` fires.

To cut down on the calls, either do as you suggested: `int cnt = context.students.Where(s=>s.schoolID == 1).Count();` which will result in 2 db calls, or create a grouped result as in [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936420/3419825)